# How to avoid running the same async task again until it got finished

Tags: android, android-asynctask, pull-to-refresh

I have implement the pull to refresh functionality in my android app and i am using async task for fetching the data from server when user do pull to refresh, but sometimes if user do pull to refresh multiple times , it request the server multiple times so duplicate data comes . I want to avoid this situation, is there any way by which i can check if the async task is running than dont run the same task again until it finished.

This is my function in which i am calling async task

```
 public void refresh()
{

if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB && !mSharedPreferences.getString("SN","").equals("") )            
            new getfeeds(getSherlockActivity()).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, (AppConstants.URL_FEED_MAIN+mSharedPreferences.getString("SN",null)+"/newer/0/"));
         else if( !mSharedPreferences.getString("SN","").equals("")  )
             new getfeeds(getSherlockActivity()).execute((AppConstants.URL_FEED_MAIN+mSharedPreferences.getString("SN","")+"/newer/0/"));       
 }
```

i want to put an condition in that if and elseif statement so it check some condition before starting getfeeds async task until previous getfeeds execution is finished

Comment: why dont you just add a static boolean field "running"?

Comment: you can check status of your task, if it is not already running then you can execute it again...

Comment: @GhostDerfel actually my asynctask resides in different class other than the main activity in which i am starting this task, so how do i access the boolean value to that different async task class.

Comment: @ShashankAgarwal try to use a broadcast receiver